# I want to blend two NLA Strips with different root positions without the character moving

Tags: animation, nla-editor

I have two animations on two tracks with different root positions.  I aligned the character so that he is standing in the same position when the tracks switch.  When I blend the tracks together, however, there is some unwanted movement of the root.  Is there a way to blend all the bones but leave the roots alone?
[image]

[image: See the root has moved but the character is in the same position.]

I need to blend the two clips so that there is no pop between the two.